# How to increase the voltage for a TFT SPI ILI9486 powered via USB?

Tags: voltage, esp8266, tft

[image]

Hello everyone,

I am new to the IoT field and have an ILI9486 SPI TFT display that can be powered between 3V and 5V. I am using pin A0, as shown in the provided schematic, to power the display using a USB cable connected to my computer. However, I am unable to get the minimum 4.0V required to properly operate the display. Currently, I am only getting 3.0V.

I would like to know if there is a solution to increase the voltage using the USB cable or if I need to use another method to power the display.

Here is the list of components I use:

[ESP8266](https://www.gotronic.fr/art-module-nodemcu-esp8266-27744.htm)
[screen tft](https://fr.aliexpress.com/i/1005001998578860.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2fra)

I thank you in advance for your help and advice.

Comment: I would also like to keep a maximum voltage of 5V on my breadboard if I plug my esp8266 to a socket

Comment: That is not a schematic. A0 is also not a voltage output and not connected to display at all. And based on wiring diagram, you are feeding a 5V supply into a 3.3V MCU so it may be damaged now. So what you describe does not match the diagram. Please fix the diagram or text, whichever is correct.